# python3: regex, find all substrings that starts with and end with certain string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Let's say that I have a string that looks like this:

```
a = '1253abcd4567efgh8910ijkl'
```

I want to find all substrings that starts with a digit, and ends with an alphabet.

I tried,

```
b = re.findall('\d.*\w',a)
```

but this gives me,

```
['1253abcd4567efgh8910ijkl']
```

I want to have something like,

```
['1234abcd','4567efgh','8910ijkl']
```

How can I do this? I'm pretty new to regex method, and would really appreciate it if anyone can show how to do this in different method within regex, and explain what's going on.

Comment: Your expected result is a little short. There are 96 substrings starting with a digit and ending on an alphabet letter possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\w` will match any *wordcharacter* which consists of numbers, alphabets and the underscore sign. You need to use `[a-zA-Z]` to capture letters only. See this example.

```
import re

a = '1253abcd4567efgh8910ijkl'
b = re.findall('(\d+[A-Za-z]+)',a)
```

Output:

```
['1253abcd', '4567efgh', '8910ijkl']
```

---

`\d` will match digits. `\d+` will match one or more consecutive digits. For e.g.

```
>>> re.findall('(\d+)',a)
['1253', '4567', '8910']
```

Similarly `[a-zA-Z]+` will match one or more alphabets.

```
>>> re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+)',a)
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl']
```

Now put them together to match what you exactly want.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Python manual on regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), it tells us that `\w`:

> matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set [a-zA-Z0-9_]

So you are actually over capturing what you need. Refine your regular expression a bit:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+[a-z]+)', a, re.I)
['1253abcd', '4567efgh', '8910ijkl']
```

The `re.I` makes your expression case insensitive, so it will match upper and lower case letters as well:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+[a-z]+)', '12124adbad13434AGDFDF434348888AAA')
['12124adbad']
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+[a-z]+)', '12124adbad13434AGDFDF434348888AAA', re.I)
['12124adbad', '13434AGDFDF', '434348888AAA']
```

Answer (score 1):

- \w matches string with any alphanumeric character. And you have used \w with *. So your code will provide a string which is starting with a digit and contains alphanumeric characters of any length.
- Solution:

  ```
  >>>b=re.findall('\d*[A-Za-z]*', a)
  >>>b
  ['1253abcd', '4567efgh', '8910ijkl', '']
  ```
- you will get '' (an empty string) at the end of the list to display no match. You can remove it using

  ```
  b.pop(-1)
  ```

Comment: what's the difference between using + and * sign? It looks like if I use +, it won't give me an empty string at the end. What does * sign do here?

Comment: + will match when there is at least 1 character. * will match even if there is no character. So * is more general. But in your case, if a=''1253abcd4567efgh8910' than b=re.findall('\d*[A-Za-z]+', a) will not return last 8910 string. But in above case, it will return ['1253abcd', '4567efgh', '8910', '']. So choose which ever is appropriate for your code.